# What could be the cause of my dogs hair pattern?

Tags: dogs, health, skin-condition

I've recently started to notice that my dog (staff, female) is getting quite patchy hair on the top of her head. She also has a bald patch on her neck that I am unable to get a picture if at this moment in time. Should I be concerned? I know that fleas are not the case as she has none

Could it be molting? Sorry if a silly question just making sure, thanks and kind regards.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure out what caused this? My dogs fur is starting to loo just like this on top of head and cheek and down back of neck.

Comment: @Amanda the user was last acctive four and a half year ago.

Answer (score 2):

This could be caused by many things, but patchy focal areas of hair loss especially on the head are typical of localised *Demodex* infection. *Demodex* is a mite that commonly affects young Staffy-type breeds. One sometimes sees pustules, papules, or blackheads and areas of redness, but not always.

Demodex is something that is quite easily treatable but you would need to go to a vet. Your vet will likely perform skin scrapings to look for *Demodex* or other possible causes. Some cases do resolve on their own, but in other cases the infestation becomes much more severe.

Obviously nobody can diagnose the cause of your dog's hair loss over the internet. Recommendation to see a veterinarian is really the only advice to give online. If this has been going on for a long time it is unlikely to get better on its own.